# Parsing POST request from Twilio in NodeJS/Express

Tags: json, node.js, express, request

I'm a Node newbie. I'm trying to figure out a way to get the data from a POST request. My code currently looks like this:

```
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/hello', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

This results in [object Object] being written instead of what I wanted. I added the bodyParser part on someone's recommendation but I don't know how to get the JSON data that Twilio sends in the body. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/hello', function(req,res){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
})
```

You are basically logging an object directly which usually means `Object.toString()` gets called directly instead of logging the body contents as JSON

Comment: Do you have any thing in the request body?